# Mixing videos in flash

Tags: flash, video, streaming

Hello is it possible to mix videos and webcamera streams in flash to send them to flash media server as one stream?

Forexample put two webcamera streams side-by side and send them to server as one steam.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't in Flash. You must send two discrete streams.  It would be possible to "mix" those streams before getting to the server, but not in Flash.